# Iterate through HTML table and filter certain column values

Tags: javascript, html-table, iteration

I am using the following JS to iterate through an html table and extract values of columns 1 and 2 from the many rows in the table, the value I get contains a bunch of information that I do not require, i.e.

I get the following of  column 1:

```
<div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
    <input name="asset_cost_19" type="text" value="$5,000.00">
</div>
```

where as I would like to only get the dollar value:

> $5,000.00

also for column 2 I get the following:

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
        <div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini">
            <label for="asset_allocation_capex_19" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-checkbox-off ui-first-child">
                Capex
            </label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="asset_allocation_capex_19" id="asset_allocation_capex_19" data-mini="true">
        </div>                                                                                                                              
        <div class="ui-checkbox ui-mini">
            <label for="asset_allocation_opex_19" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-checkbox-on ui-btn-active ui-last-child">
                Opex
            </label>
           <input type="checkbox" name="asset_allocation_opex_19" id="asset_allocation_opex_19" data-mini="true" checked="">
        </div>                                                                                                                          
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

where as I would like to know which of **asset_allocation_opex_** or **asset_allocation_capex_** is checked i.e.

> checked=""

see row 11 as an example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="asset_allocation_opex_11" id="asset_allocation_opex_11" data-mini="true" checked="">    
<input type="checkbox" name="asset_allocation_capex_11" id="asset_allocation_capex_11" data-mini="true">
```

**Code:**

```
$("#myTable_asset").children("tbody").children("tr").each(function (i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    var my_td = $this.children("td");
    var second_col = my_td.eq(1);
    var third_col = my_td.eq(2);
    console.log("Second Column Value (row " + i + "): " + second_col.html());
    console.log("Third Column Value (row " + i + "): " + third_col.html());
});
```

Comment: So you can just extract the necessary data, for example with jQuery function `attr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.find()` to get `<input type="text">` child node of `second_col`, `.val()` to get the value of an `<input>` element and `.map()` to return the values of `<input type="checkbox">` as an array

```
var text = second_col.find(":text").val();
var checkboxes = third_col.find(":checkbox")
                 .map(function(_, el) { return el.checked }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
console.log("Second Column Value (row " + i + "): " + second_col.html());
```

to

```
console.log("Second Column Value (row " + i + "): " + second_col.find("input[type=text]").val());
```